# Is view.leadingAnchor.constraint higher precedence than view.trailingAnchor.constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have my ViewController code as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "Hello World!"

        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

I'm expecting my "Hello World!" to be center aligned. Why wasn't it center aligned? (Vertically it is centered, but horizontally it is aligned to left as shown below.)

p/s: If I remove `itleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)`, then it is aligned right.

[image]

Comment: `titleLabel.textAlignment = .center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want your label to ***cover the entire view*** with the text centered? If so, keep your constraints as they are and set `.textAlignment = .center`.

I've set the background color of the label to cyan so you can see what's happening:

[image]

However, I suspect you just want your label centered in the view. In that case, change your constraints to this:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    ])
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Until and unless we are not changing priority of constraint the default priority is 1000 for all. So no precedence setting automatically.

For your code, add this line and it will work.

```
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 and later, the default value of `textAlignment` property of `UILabel` is [NSTextAlignment.natural](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextalignment/natural), prior to iOS 9, the default value was [NSTextAlignment.left](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620541-textalignment)

If you want your label to cover the entire view with the text-centered then your constraints are perfect, just set

```
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
```